# What's the difference between $\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z^+$ and $\mathbb Z^+\to\mathbb Z$?

Tags: functions

What's the difference between $\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z^+$ and $\mathbb Z^+\to\mathbb Z$? Are they same, and if not, why not?

I encountered this problem in following multiple choice question:

> Which one of the following functions is injecive?
>
> 1. $ f : \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z $ with $ f ( x ) = x ^ 2 $
> 2. $ f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R $ with $ f ( x ) = x ^ 2 $
> 3. $ f : \mathbb Z ^ + \to \mathbb Z $ with $ f ( x ) = x ^ 2 $
> 4. $ f : \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z ^ + $ with $ f ( x ) = x ^ 2 $

I chose 4 but it was incorrect.

Comment: $f(x):\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}^+:x\mapsto x^2$ is clearly not injective, since for example $f(-2) = f(2)=4$. See if you can figure out what the other function is saying.

Comment: @rogerl  I don't see how that can be at all clear if the OP doesn't know what $\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z^+$ means... which *was* the OPs question.

Comment: What's the difference? The first is the domain, the second the target, if we have $f:A\rightarrow B$. So they are not the same.

Comment: fleablood is right I wanted to know what was the difference between Z--->Z+ and Z+--->Z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation $A \to B$ means you are mapping the elements of $A$ to the elements of $B$.

So

$f:\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z^+$  means you are taking the values $\{.....,-3,-2,-1, 0,1,2,3,....\}$ and mapping them to $\{0, 1,2,3,4.....\}$

And $f:\mathbb Z^+ \to \mathbb Z$ means you are taking the values $\{0, 1,2,3,4,....\}$ and mapping them to $\{.....,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,......\}$.

There first function is *not* injective because we can have $f(k) = f(j) = m^2; k\ne j$ by letting $k=m; j=-m$ so $j\ne k$. So there can be more than one element in $\mathbb Z$ can map to the same element in $\mathbb Z^+$.  So it is not injective.

The second one *is* injective because if $f(k) = f(j) = m^2$ then $j=k=m$ and $j = -k$ is not possible because there are no negative numbers in $\mathbb Z^+$. So we can *not* have more more than element of $\mathbb Z^+$ mapping to the same element of $\mathbb Z$.  So it *is* injective

Comment: "This not an injective function because there is no unique Y-value for every X-value." Not quite.  It is not injective as for every Y-value there are need not be a unique X-value. "This a surjective function"  Well no it isn't.  If $m$ is not a perfect square then $f(x) = m$ doesnt happen.  There is no $x$ so that $f(x) = x^2 = 3$. ... but a good example would be $g(x)=|x|$.  then $g:\mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z^+$ is not injective but is surjective.  And $g:\mathbb Z^+\to \mathbb Z$ is surective but not injective. $g:\mathbb Z^+\to\mathbb Z^+$ is both.$g:\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z$ is neither.

Comment: Oh... $f(x) =x^2$ and $f: \mathbb R\to \mathbb R^+$ would be surjective but not injective.  And if we defined $\mathbb Z^{2+} = \{0,1,2^2, 3^2,....\} =\{0,1,4,9,16,.....\}$ (that is *NOT* standard notation--  I just made it up) then $f:\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z^{2+}$ is surjective (but not injective).  .... I might as well introduce you to this concept.  If $f: A \to B$ and $Image(f) = f(A) = \{f(x)|x\in A\}$ then $Image(f)=f(A) \subseteq B$ and $f:A \to Image(f)=f(A)$ is *ALWAYS* surjective for *any* function.  But if $Im(A)=f(A) \subsetneq B$ then $f:A \to B$ is *not* surjective.

Comment: Let me see if I got this right. In the second part Z+ ---> Z we are only taking positive integers from the domain Z+ as X-value inputs and mapping them (or outputting them) to the codomain Z  (Y-value outputs) which includes both positive and negative integers, however since there is no positive X-value integer input which maps to a negative Y-value integer output in the function f(x)=x^2. What we are left with are only positive X-value integers which map to unique Y-value integers hence thus by limiting our X-value inputs we just created a one to one function. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Z+ are only the positiv z so with Z+ -->Z it is injective, Z-->Z+ ist not injected since -1 and 1 have the same image under x^2 and Z-->Z and Z-->Z+ are the same since x^2>=0

Answer (score 1):

Writing $f:\mathbb{Z}^+\to \mathbb{Z}$ means that you are only allowed to write $f(x)$ for $x\in \mathbb{Z}^+$ (that is, $x$ is a non-negative integer) and that $f(x)$ lies in $\mathbb{Z}$.

On the other hand, writing $f:\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}^+$ means that you are only allowed to write $f(x)$ for $x\in \mathbb{Z}$ (that is, $x$ is an integer) and that $f(x)$ lies in $\mathbb{Z}^+$.

A function $f:A\to B$ is called injective, if $f(x)=f(y)$ implies $x=y$. In other words, plugging two different values into $f$ must result in two different results.

Your choice was incorrect, because the given function isn't injective: $f(1)=f(-1)$ (so two different inputs did not result in two different outputs).

Comment: It's alright fleeblood explained it what your saying is that in f: Z+ ---> Z f(x)=X^2 we are taking elements from the Z+ domain and outputting them to elements in the Z codomain, but since Z+ will only ever give us positive integers in the codomain we have essentially taken part of the function (hence partial function) by limiting our input we have also limited our output and created an injective one to one function from a surjective function.

Comment: @edwardkenway Well, $f: \mathbb{Z}^+\to \mathbb{Z}$ isn't surjective. For example, we cannot find $x\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $f(x)=-1$.

Comment: correct thank you so much your help and support I truly appreciate your help.